# Constant velocity in rotate animation

Tags: android, animation

I am using `RotateAnimation` to spin an `ImageView` to a certain degree (my ImageView is a circle).

```
degree_old = degree % 360;
degree = random_sector.nextInt(3600) + 720;
```

This is the code I use for the first spin:

```
final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, degree, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(5000);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(0);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

And this code to spin to the start position again:

```
 final RotateAnimation rotateBack = new RotateAnimation(degree, (back_degree + degree), RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                            0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    rotateBack.setDuration(3000);
                    rotateBack.setFillAfter(true);
                    rotateBack.setRepeatCount(0);
                    rotateBack.setRepeatMode(0);
                    rotateBack.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

It works.

My problem is that the speed rotation isn't the same every time. Sometimes it spins with a very high velocity and other time with a very low velocity.

My question is: Is there a way to have every time the same velocity? I prefer my animation to spin with a low velocity for 5 seconds.

How can I change the the spinning speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are wanting to use only RotateAnimation.

The following code will rotate an Image 360 degrees and back again very smoothly.
Obviously you can adjust this code to include your random generator.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView my_image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_image = findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    animate_it();
}

private void animate_it() {
    my_image.setRotation(0);
    my_image.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(5000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            my_image.animate().rotation(0).setDuration(5000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answers but it doesn't work because I am using another `RotateAnimation` to spin the `ImageView` to the starting position.
I updated my question.

Comment: I created and tested this small program. It looks really smooth. Maybe you can use this?

Comment: Thanks for helping me! After setting your code up to match my `degree` I just found the issue. It was here `degree = random_sector.nextInt(3600) + 720;` , instead of using  `3600`  I could use a lower number as `720` to get a lower angle to rotate to. So in the end both ur code and mine just works grate! Thanks again for helping me to find the issue!